# combining strptime and strftime loops

Tags: python, python-3.x

How might I combine these loops where I extract date strings, recognize them with strptime, and reformat them with strftime?

```
datesandcontent = [elm.get_text() for elm in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : "review-content"})]
dates = [re.search(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)', elm).group(1) for elm in datesandcontent]
dates2 = [datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y') for date in dates]
dates3 = [datetime.strftime(date2, '%Y-%m-%d') for date2 in dates2]
```

Comment: for readability and your own sanity, don't repeatedly chain into one long "one-line" expression. try and split out. I gave one solution which avoids multiple  loops and is also readable, but there will be alternatives.

Comment: thanks for the tip - readability is important. compose looks like a good package for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain the methods.

```
dates2 = [datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for date in dates]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can chain the expressions:

```
dates = [datetime.strptime(re.search(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)', elm.get_text()).group(1), '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') 
         for elm in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : "review-content"})]
```

`strftime()` is a method on a `datetime` instance. Using `datoetime.strftime(dt, ...)` works because you reference the unbound method, but it's better to just use it on the instances.

The above isn't all that readable of course. I'd still split up the expressions, but you can use *generator expressions* to chain processing:

```
date_strings = (re.search(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)', elm.get_text()).group(1)
                for elm in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : "review-content"}))
dates = [datetime.strptime(ds, '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%Y-%m-%d') for ds in date_strings]
```

This separates text handling from HTML, and reformatting those strings to a different date format, in twe separate expressions, but builds just one list. The iteration over `date_strings` processes BeautifulSoup elements on demand.

Answer (score 1):

This is one readable way:

```
from toolz import compose

def get_text(x): return x.get_text()
def searcher(x): return re.search(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)', x).group(1)
def strp1(x): return datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y')
def strp2(x): return datetime.strftime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')

calculator = compose(strp2, strp1, searcher, get_text)

result = list(map(calculator, soup.find_all('div', {'class' : "review-content"})))
```